# How to change resource image to one with the same name but different suffix?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `ToolStrip` with a `ContextMenu`, like so:

[image]

I have 2 icons in my Resources, like so:

[image]

I'm trying to switch out the icons to their 16x16 counterparts:

```
void largeIconsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ContextItem = (ToolStripMenuItem) sender;
    var ContextMenu = (ContextMenuStrip) ContextItem.Owner;
    var ToolStrip = (ToolStrip) ContextMenu.SourceControl;
    var Checked = ContextItem.Checked;

    ToolStrip.ImageScalingSize = Checked ? new Size(32, 32) : new Size(16, 16);

    foreach(ToolStripButton Button in ToolStrip.Items)
        Button.Image = Resources.t_new16;
}
```

This works, but I don't want to add a new line in my `foreach` for each individual icon. How can I substitute the Resource name to `t_icon16`, where it is currently `t_icon32`?

I tried looking for a `Name` property in `Button.Image`, but there isn't one.

I also tried:

```
foreach(ToolStripButton Button in ToolStrip.Items)
    foreach(PropertyItem P in Button.Image.PropertyItems)
        MessageBox.Show(P.Id.ToString() + " - " + P.Value.ToString());
```

But no `MessageBox`es are shown.

How can I swap the resource image dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Create two image lists - one with small icons, and another with large icons (in same order):

```
toolStrip.ImageList = smallImageList;
toolStripButton1.ImageIndex = 0;
toolStripButton2.ImageIndex = 1;
```

And just switch between lists:

```
toolStrip.ImageList = largeImageList;
```

Comment: I managed to do this without having to maintain 2 lists of images (see my answer); but thanks a lot for taking the time to answer!

Comment: I don't think that maintaining tags of all buttons is better, but it's up to you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this without having to maintain 2 lists of images.

Firstly, the `ToolStripButton` needs to have its `Tag` property set to the name of the initial resource:

[image]

With that set, this code handles the rest dynamically:

```
void largeIconsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ResourceManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources));
    var ContextItem = (ToolStripMenuItem) sender;
    var ContextMenu = (ContextMenuStrip) ContextItem.Owner;
    var ToolStrip = (ToolStrip) ContextMenu.SourceControl;
    var Checked = ContextItem.Checked;

    ToolStrip.ImageScalingSize = Checked ? new Size(32, 32) : new Size(16, 16);

    foreach(ToolStripButton Button in ToolStrip.Items)
    {
        var CurrentResource = Button.Tag.ToString();
        var NewResource = CurrentResource.Substring(0, CurrentResource.Length - 2) + (Checked ? "32" : "16");
        Button.Image = (Image) ResourceManager.GetObject(NewResource);
        Button.Tag = NewResource;
    }
}
```